# undefined is not a function (evaluating this.function(time.week_date) in react native

Tags: react-native

I using map function for repeat my view. I try to get a proper value when i click my button i used like this but it showing the error

weeklySheet =(val)=>{
        this.props.navigator.push({
         name: 'Timesheet',
         title: 'Timesheet',
         passProps:{
             startDate:val
         },
         openMenu: this.openMenu
        });
    }

{this.state.UserValid.map(function(time){
                return(
             this.weeklySheet(time.week_date)}>
            
                
                    {time.week_date}
                
                
                    {time.hours}
                
            
            
       );

Comment: Could you please provide more context for the code? Maybe the whole component to see what the state looks like) And please use the formating options.

Comment: weeklySheet =(val)=>{
        this.props.navigator.push({
         name: 'Timesheet',
         title: 'Timesheet',
         passProps:{
             startDate:val
         },
         openMenu: this.openMenu
        });
    }

Comment: Please use proper formatting. Also, there still seems to be code missing. Where does the latter part of your code go? It looks like it should be inside a react component but you posted it floating outside weeklySheet.